# need a download manager for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, download-manager

hi i recently shifted to ubuntu 10.4.. and need a download manager. I was very comfortable with FDM(free download manager) on windows, which used to do everything form download huge file with pause and resume, download torrents, increase download speed and everything thats required.
Is there a suitable for FDM on linux?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using firefox as your browser you could use [DownThemAll !](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.downthemall.net%2F&ei=S7E1TJXvFM_xOeKU7f0F&usg=AFQjCNF9kp_66HwERLyTP0JaA_eUoz-Vjw&sig2=WAr-Gu2lKwvfsCkj7XIxdw)

Alternatively, you could take a look at:

[WxDownload Fast](http://dfast.sourceforge.net/index.html)

[Kget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGet)

[Gwget](http://projects.gnome.org/gwget/)

Again, if using firefox look at
[FlashGot](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddons.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Ffirefox%2Faddon%2F220%2F&ei=GrI1TKa_O5TzOfD7sRQ&usg=AFQjCNETPSABBTRpGHC0QVGtqlJbNMJENg&sig2=ZX5E2L2w__aWrh6NecHldg) it's a great addon for working with various download managers

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look for a GUI frontend for a program like wget or curl.